# Not able to create an object of both the class why in c#?

Tags: c#, class, oop

I had created two class namely A & B Here is the code given below

```
class Program
{
    public class A
    {
        public int add(int x, int y)
        {
            return x + y;
        }
    }

    public class B:A
    {
        public int sub(int x, int y)
        {
            return x - y;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A t = new A();
        t.add(10,20);
        B r = new B();
        r.sub(20, 10);
        A B
    }
}
```

Class B is inherited from Class A But when I want to make an object

```
A B = new AB();
```

of both the class AB then it is not able to create an object. What is the reason behind this?

Comment: If want to create class of type `A`, then you should do `A B = new A()` instead of `new AB()`

Comment: read some fundamentals of c# and oops comcepts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code already shows you making a `new A()` and a `new B()`. There *is* no `AB()`. By the nature of inheritance, a `B` *is already* an `A`; *every* `B` is also an `A` - just a more specific sub-type.

```
A B = new AB();
```

says "declare `B` to be a new variable of type `A`, and assign it the reference to a new instance of `AB`". This would actually even compile if you create `class AB : A`. It probably isn't what you meant to do, though.

Answer (score 1):

`B = new B();` is enough.

The name should be exactly how you defined the classname. The names aren't composited. In your case, class `B` is inherited from class `A` and will contain all functionality of class `A`.

For example:

```
B b = new B();

int sum = b.add(10, 30);
int difference = b.sub(10, 30);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no class `AB`

If want to create class of type `A`, then you should do `A B = new A();` instead of `A B = new AB();`

Also since `B` is derived from `A`, if you create `B`, you could access all the `protected/public` properties, fields, and methods from the instance of class `B`:

```
B b = new B();
b.add(); //this is B but use class A method, it is OK
```

So, you could just create object instance of class `B`

Answer (score 0):

Please read some basics of c# language syntax and [C# Programming/Inheritance](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Sharp_Programming/Inheritance) article.

Answer (score 0):

By using inherit this means you are adding to a base class..... so when you created B you said inherit A...this means your methods in B (ie .sub ) are available but also all methods in A (ie .add).

So to do an AB all you have to do is use B...as that has both of these in it as defined by B b = new B();

Plus your confusing the yourself with these names;
A should be AddValues, B should be AddandSubtractValues thus clearly documenting you code...it will help you later